# Change the powerline name for nerdtree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, plugin-powerline

How do I change the name of Nerdtree tab in the powerline where it displays filename

Rightnow it displays it as `~/dir/dir/NERD_tree_1`

I just want it to be displayed `Nerd Tree`

Comment: Have you had any luck with the answer I posted? It should be exactly what you need (except, perhaps, for a tweak to the substitution pattern).

Comment: @BLayer I tried changing patterns, it didn't work

Comment: What do you currently see when you do `:echo g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod` ?

Comment: It says undefined variable for some reason. Does it have to do that I have powerline installed and not airline?

Comment: Oh, shoot, man...I screwed up...mixed the two up! (I use both.) Sorry about that. I'll look for a solution for powerline.

Comment: What do you see when you do `:set tabline?` ?

Comment: @BLayer `tabline=`  this is the output

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. I don't see any Powerline specific configuration to do what you want but I have some info/suggestions that I'll post as soon as I have some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation and code I don't see any straightforward way to do customization like that. There are some basic modifications that can be done [to the directory portion of the path](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/segments/vim.html#powerline.segments.vim.file_directory) and [the file
part](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/segments/vim.html#powerline.segments.vim.file_name) but we're talking about basic things like converting `/home/foo.bar/` to `~foo.bar`.

But are you sure you're actually using Powerline for your
tabline? Because it is configured with the `'tabline'` setting and you
said yours was not set to anything. As you can see [near the end of this
code](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/powerline/vim.html) Powerline writes to that setting *if tabline is configured.*

Either way there are no easy solutions.

- If you are using Powerline for your tabline then you could modify the code I linked to above (e.g. by looking for the Nerd Tree filename and doing some substitution).
- If you are *not* using Powerline for your tabline then you can modify `'tabline'` per `:help  setting-tabline` but some of the text in that helpfile might dissuade you:

> The 'tabline' option allows you to define your preferred way to tab pages labels.  **This isn't easy**.

Even with the example they provide you're facing a challenge as it does not show how to bring the back the complete set of features enabled by the default tabline settings.

TBH, your best bet, if you really want to change this, is to switch to `vim-airline`. You can fully modify paths via the `:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod` variable. I've used both and I prefer airline. It's much more lightweight (pure Vim, no Python) but still has everything I want and looks great. Even Powerline's docs mention this as a good alternative:

> You should check out some of the Powerline derivatives. The most lightweight and feature-rich alternative is currently Bailey Ling’s vim-airline project.

Comment: I shifted to airline .. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Good choice.. You're welcome.